# WebApi Environment.NewLine is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When i write var line = Environment.NewLine; Im getting as `\r\n\`  Insted of new Line

My Code as

```
 var line = Environment.NewLine;
    Body = "Hi," + line +"The new "+ master.CATEGORY_NAME
```

My O/p as

```
"Body": "Hi,\r\n\r\nThe new
```

Comment: \r\n -is- the newline string for Windows, so it works as intended. What exactly are you trying do achieve?

Comment: @Bas After Hi I want Then new is comes in next line

Comment: That's how you specify a new line, with \r\n. It looks like you're trying to output json, which ignores whitespace like newlines. Putting "The new..." on the next line wouldn't do anything, the JSON structure would be the same. If you want whatever is using your JSON output to see a newline symbol between Hi and The, the \r\n string is what you need.

Comment: @Bas  My Outpu is Line This please suggest me how can i break line after Hi         [
    {
            "Body": "Hi,\r\nThe new TAB enquiry for Nokia with the Enquiry ID 1-1819-1 registered by Varsha Thimmaiah is sent for your review.Please login to Enquiry Management System to approve the enquiry.\r\n"
    }
]

Comment: What is using the output of this JSON? Are you writing it to a text file, to an email, a web page?

Comment: @Bas Yes  im writing for an Email

Comment: If you write "Hi,\r\nThe" in the email body, it will come out the way you want it, as long as the email is plaintext. If you are sending an HTML email, instead of environment.newline, use "<br />".

Comment: But when i test with Post Man Its not working

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question. Try set the response content-type to "text/plain":

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```